# How to subtract a column from another specific column using an identifier

Tags: r, dataframe, finance

We have Net Asset Values (NAV) over several years for over 100 mutual funds where the mutual funds start and end at different dates.

The NAVs are monthly and we also made a column marking them with a number for  each month (1-12) and the year. We also have monthly risk free return, where we did the same by making a column and marking them with a number for each month (1-12) and the year.

We now need to subtract the right monthly risk free asset to the dedicated NAV. The data for the risk free return and the NAV are in different data frames. We have pulled 50 lines from each data frames if this helps illustrate the problem/create a solution.

Here is a selection of the data frame for the NAV (`dput(dfNAV[1:50,]`):

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(11075, 11108, 11138, 11169, 
11200, 11229, 11261, 11291, 11320, 11353, 11381, 11411, 11442, 
11473, 11502, 11534, 11565, 11593, 11625, 11626, 11656, 11684, 
11718, 11746, 11773, 11807, 11838, 11866, 11899, 11929, 11960, 
11991, 12020, 12051, 12083, 12111, 12142, 12172, 12202, 12233, 
12264, 12293, 12325, 12356, 12384, 12416, 12447, 12475, 12508, 
12538), class = "Date"), SecurityId = c(45731, 45731, 45731, 
45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 
45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 
45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 
45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 
45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 
45731, 45731), FundId = c(109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 
109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 
109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 
109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 
109, 109, 109, 109), Symbol = c("AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", 
"AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", 
"AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", 
"AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", 
"AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", 
"AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", 
"AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", 
"AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", 
"AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2"), 
    ISIN = c("NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", 
    "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", 
    "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", 
    "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", 
    "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", 
    "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", 
    "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", 
    "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", 
    "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", 
    "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", 
    "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", 
    "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", 
    "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576"), Name = c("ABIF Norge ++", 
    "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", 
    "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", 
    "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", 
    "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", 
    "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", 
    "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", 
    "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", 
    "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", 
    "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", 
    "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", 
    "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", 
    "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", 
    "ABIF Norge ++"), NAV = c(96.9792, 102.1109, 105.2352, 110.6285, 
    120.5222, 117.2032, 115.133, 104.2482, 102.1704, 103.0578, 
    103.8683, 94.8068, 100.8107, 102.9584, 98.032, 96.01, 90.43, 
    77.27, 78.62, 78.62, 83.27, 86.17, 85.497, 87.3472, 93.9374, 
    88.8757, 86.9814, 79.075, 74.3745, 71.6498, 60.0066, 64.1799, 
    70.2522, 62.9072, 60.6429, 56.8225, 57.1645, 64.3922, 67.9668, 
    72.9443, 79.293, 84.1295, 78.0903, 88.6589, 89.6975, 94.9707, 
    103.4249, 112.0345, 106.0645, 102.2011), NAV2 = c(102.1109, 
    105.2352, 110.6285, 120.5222, 117.2032, 115.133, 104.2482, 
    102.1704, 103.0578, 103.8683, 94.8068, 100.8107, 102.9584, 
    98.032, 96.01, 90.43, 77.27, 78.62, 78.62, 83.27, 86.17, 
    85.497, 87.3472, 93.9374, 88.8757, 86.9814, 79.075, 74.3745, 
    71.6498, 60.0066, 64.1799, 70.2522, 62.9072, 60.6429, 56.8225, 
    57.1645, 64.3922, 67.9668, 72.9443, 79.293, 84.1295, 78.0903, 
    88.6589, 89.6975, 94.9707, 103.4249, 112.0345, 106.0645, 
    102.2011, 103.5399), NAV3 = c(5.1317, 3.12430000000001, 5.3933, 
    9.8937, -3.319, -2.0702, -10.8848, -2.0778, 0.8874, 0.810500000000005, 
    -9.06150000000001, 6.0039, 2.1477, -4.9264, -2.02199999999999, 
    -5.58, -13.16, 1.35000000000001, 0, 4.64999999999999, 2.90000000000001, 
    -0.673000000000002, 1.8502, 6.5902, -5.0617, -1.8943, -7.90639999999999, 
    -4.70050000000001, -2.7247, -11.6432, 4.1733, 6.0723, -7.345, 
    -2.26430000000001, -3.8204, 0.341999999999999, 7.22770000000001, 
    3.5746, 4.97749999999999, 6.34870000000001, 4.83649999999999, 
    -6.03919999999999, 10.5686, 1.0386, 5.27319999999999, 8.4542, 
    8.6096, -5.97, -3.8634, 1.33880000000001), rjt1 = c(0.0529154705338876, 
    0.0305971252824136, 0.0512499619899045, 0.0894317467921918, 
    -0.0275384949826671, -0.0176633402500956, -0.0945410959499014, 
    -0.0199312793889966, 0.00868549012238378, 0.00786451874579124, 
    -0.0872402840905263, 0.0633277359851825, 0.0213042861521644, 
    -0.0478484514133864, -0.0206259180675697, -0.0581189459431309, 
    -0.145526926904788, 0.0174712048660542, 0, 0.0591452556601373, 
    0.0348264681157681, -0.00781014274109321, 0.021640525398552, 
    0.0754483257620164, -0.0538837566294149, -0.0213140374703097, 
    -0.0908975941982998, -0.0594435662345875, -0.0366348681335673, 
    -0.162501500353106, 0.069547349791523, 0.0946137342065039, 
    -0.104551885919587, -0.0359942900017805, -0.0629983064794065, 
    0.00601874257556424, 0.126436862038503, 0.0555129347964506, 
    0.0732342849744286, 0.0870349019731495, 0.0609952959277614, 
    -0.0717845702161548, 0.135338191811275, 0.0117145599595754, 
    0.0587887064856879, 0.0890190342916289, 0.0832449439158269, 
    -0.0532871570810777, -0.0364250055390823, 0.0130996633108646
    ), NAVAdj = c(95.1845744125828, 100.221310955192, 103.287794962456, 
    108.581290528303, 118.2919050092, 115.034323976614, 113.002433571775, 
    102.319059656894, 100.279709892053, 103.0578, 103.8683, 94.8068, 
    100.8107, 102.9584, 98.032, 96.01, 90.43, 77.27, 78.62, 78.62, 
    83.27, 86.17, 85.497, 87.3472, 93.9374, 88.8757, 86.9814, 
    79.075, 74.3745, 71.6498, 60.0066, 64.1799, 70.2522, 62.9072, 
    60.6429, 56.8225, 57.1645, 64.3922, 67.9668, 72.9443, 79.293, 
    84.1295, 78.0903, 88.6589, 89.6975, 94.9707, 103.4249, 112.0345, 
    106.0645, 102.2011), Dividends = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), CorpAdj = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1), DividendAdj = c(0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 
    0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 
    0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), lnDeltaNAV = c(0.0274417964293168, 
    -0.00350766756849463, 0.00998840819124958, 0.000928763378170494, 
    0.00791108635966342, 0.00864194816233166, 0.0144252428438243, 
    -0.0326130578043271, -0.000906896436772442, 0.0126041093498408, 
    -0.00361822884525953, 0.0137502969599446, 0.00861446066174043, 
    0.00181597289005087, 0.00621623692463391, 0.00187656435386163, 
    -0.00749149697337792, 0.0181526368786793, -0.00722390822860675, 
    0, 0.0120818190668892, 0.00651999049728147, 0.00636429145621165, 
    -0.00450742957110783, 0.007965648824654, 0.00144350537836235, 
    0.00449610891723751, 0.0141470222220663, 0.0160980643167319, 
    0.00923443722576689, -0.0174515619285609, 0.0184013947690973, 
    0.0168046574519067, -0.00552145578478402, 0.00526092497346831, 
    0.0249322910975858, -0.00910223547118605, -0.0030717369529274, 
    0.00436310066319034, -0.0101492557568088, 0.00870181996162334, 
    0.00853512319797645, -0.0131162685292976, 0.00180968961233052, 
    -0.000929359811573605, -0.00146569351793957, 0.00399055160518813, 
    0.0116587725257133, 0.0118800845637939, -0.00930675043732698
    ), lnDeltaOSEBX = c(0.0261622502400947, -0.00321159549991012, 
    0.00877033643413938, -0.00298091132522149, 0.0093168319222956, 
    0.00320695110539315, 0.0165507812371484, -0.0298292017516539, 
    -0.00279652124476559, 0.0128843812454127, -0.00303229783678471, 
    0.013455173619171, 0.00844688176370578, 0.000198668918900857, 
    0.00878666740983025, 0.00149620632806879, -0.00542067956352454, 
    0.0164522493491743, -0.00743251148673707, 0.0015308332717634, 
    0.00688373048850099, 0.00636065750845738, 0.00791876701747452, 
    -0.00349924942280122, 0.00813080992677406, 0.00511540142367028, 
    0.000964785410099367, 0.00520043045522645, 0.0146031063223155, 
    0.0120183633609647, -0.0180072054930731, 0.0162186590242435, 
    0.0168797256037649, -0.00950249030098504, 0.00365230500953562, 
    0.0221866534871467, -0.0125138949724395, -0.00085019559618793, 
    0.00396970384108641, -0.00986918851126362, 0.0101242708762337, 
    0.00582882341227275, -0.0120011170711791, 0.00305863406128282, 
    -0.00126729393020675, -0.00102163828770063, 0.00111638801472491, 
    0.0125382559692175, 0.012051247355787, -0.00862553863431081
    ), lnDeltaOBX = c(0.0222017092722471, -0.0035685318306351, 
    0.00927676647155717, -0.00322304642514126, 0.0122551306827603, 
    0.00386787017854395, 0.0194385117533802, -0.0349171093011842, 
    -0.00278043845655773, 0.0139050884791985, -0.00414777441337044, 
    0.0142337087252509, 0.0057961116712848, 0.000651260999012138, 
    0.00971445011483674, -0.000169194513667925, -0.00341789790426716, 
    0.0164112903997351, -0.00431485533650289, 0.00159580908248547, 
    0.00785272123002656, 0.00690128271707913, 0.00951926939242664, 
    -0.0043473603954407, 0.00818085801734103, 0.0063764434870901, 
    0.000407697331152867, 0.00793118483108124, 0.0150475541343758, 
    0.0128103004688169, -0.020196700812475, 0.017542971445617, 
    0.0179025661212791, -0.0113010728926346, 0.00432265578068325, 
    0.022434417862141, -0.0134021747347655, -0.00119436954337626, 
    0.00357711390482063, -0.00939315654505801, 0.0097484878707963, 
    0.00633488935549487, -0.011368112232053, 0.00311730494447282, 
    -0.00177851354914704, -0.0011414403065606, 0.00131284335288306, 
    0.0134264862303022, 0.0122844071888668, -0.00834517033849469
    ), lnDeltaOSEFX = c(0.0257512997592757, -0.00372148073099599, 
    0.00863973580821575, -0.00106204557498124, 0.0106894615262938, 
    0.0043754864256611, 0.0159813273910201, -0.033739462051023, 
    -0.00115459832436304, 0.0169207077575786, -0.00252612142439101, 
    0.0133094452453415, 0.00874908927566054, 0.00156455350865237, 
    0.00935258615825063, 0.00210095145298173, -0.00669794868412765, 
    0.0189215912698213, -0.00702817435321279, 0.00171232918551212, 
    0.00826014695620181, 0.00769553315353733, 0.00748064914645585, 
    -0.00351536096517346, 0.00896667197876688, 0.00239843339403389, 
    0.00460021391112875, 0.00876155976649162, 0.0124992436782625, 
    0.0106821380787201, -0.0180185055026785, 0.0163219842019382, 
    0.0181032895656239, -0.00942662125770344, 0.00430541589352629, 
    0.0233840751896519, -0.0112301415394915, 0.000507099402346611, 
    0.0056122358569386, -0.0093353018181288, 0.0101169263563117, 
    0.00645370897866204, -0.0119826580096527, 0.00289795984104302, 
    -0.00118964994019422, -0.00101162425117707, 0.00108611264251124, 
    0.0112418638169585, 0.0123434512360125, -0.00799426509711854
    ), SMB = c(0.00577986123704642, -0.00654011695984795, 0.0042588988477663, 
    -0.00577331652338534, -0.0128639051842341, -0.00282361989948447, 
    0.00926942672948123, -0.00159407144589641, -0.0234783005655727, 
    -0.00712297032430234, -0.0103213035279293, -0.00274604330460397, 
    -0.00466656929061131, -0.016816204260033, 8.58868959707285e-05, 
    -0.00799362290455943, 0.0038569537689772, -0.00677190397492088, 
    -0.00325934114735501, -0.0131595260940676, -0.0138924648790215, 
    0.0047656486529241, -0.00882280401870713, 0.00220287755331112, 
    -0.00790663911810646, 0.0128617254989806, -0.00624980745789196, 
    -0.0136368562338606, 0.0630771668546433, 0.0107550772971999, 
    0.00306313865369983, -0.00396381765801874, 0.0103787458202975, 
    -0.00877208964029707, 0.010554989886919, -0.00653487522327196, 
    -0.000389941615042667, 0.00227263868503461, -0.00848834855427348, 
    0.00943392498685034, -0.00557964548727661, 0.0124905605143232, 
    -0.00503318580725495, 0.00666531888024076, -0.0091831606237863, 
    -0.0141424474419593, -0.00906710036216694, 0.00760686358551667, 
    -0.00124867551633826, -0.0181691134987367), HML = c(-0.0400042937351153, 
    -0.0066708890999078, -0.00419892195763534, -0.0126775428108015, 
    -0.00907053024252952, 0.00176516902952155, -0.0140367618275742, 
    0.0270935738643608, 0.03025856502234, -0.0527335412243866, 
    -0.00265341704033851, 0.00475360385405994, 0.00613501648347071, 
    -0.00942339106863356, -0.017331328652346, 0.0102991439232348, 
    -0.00463866874691798, -0.00331670280829294, 0.0229807160745823, 
    -0.00680235096559611, 0.00552054376258217, 0.00109237331414049, 
    0.00261458884438971, 0.0167873311409555, -0.0116522606180712, 
    0.0145650942717742, -0.00830491968957432, -0.039973484903717, 
    -0.0367393701558186, 0.00697739820072437, 0.00884361674558607, 
    -0.032840145392728, 0.0188258170277682, -0.0080056184346814, 
    -0.000458489075829557, -0.0163708246599241, -0.0124225215058817, 
    NA, NA, -0.00888163441824433, 0.00267831319710646, -0.00496799083371276, 
    -0.00919771554021466, -0.00460054257751681, -0.01621692091088, 
    0.00814398108360904, -0.0103096795565, 0.00892735825198374, 
    0.0227557744740985, -0.00662193818332601), LIQ = c(-0.022369198083528, 
    0.0109845718520624, 0.0126788650487981, -0.00390201311323077, 
    0.00218050955131144, -0.0075959006271329, -0.00472483077475601, 
    0.00202996721820105, -0.0250449822597611, -0.00240069235579592, 
    0.00549835828400511, 0.00516517901008896, 0.00916860958085313, 
    0.0106929351484122, -0.0051815662059857, 0.000696733033235412, 
    -0.000478810098465092, -0.000147859788642631, -0.00926146895254349, 
    -0.00231258856162509, 0.00809611952583837, -0.00342299562292894, 
    0.00920161170178944, 0.00409966031023438, -0.00224480953984, 
    0.00817492288048398, 0.00299702126025813, -0.0039256704923854, 
    0.0783583024052581, -0.0119548733328832, 0.0226106399034113, 
    -0.0144970365164012, -0.00704842269310637, -0.00328544233296126, 
    -0.00152294642033654, -0.0012896602274351, 0.000839099896853023, 
    0.00760407607039239, 0.0283869119462006, 0.0148955895293236, 
    -0.00684754090040982, 0.012572323327271, -0.00645029371019245, 
    -0.000893370044570502, -0.00404915711882918, -0.00304640620093957, 
    0.00243945219102138, -0.00447910768154185, -0.0056372505556088, 
    0.00615880353476153), MOM = c(0.016500139365733, -0.00659043125965345, 
    -0.0105040752034117, -0.0129415244955013, 0.0154902420604264, 
    0.00262134695016149, 0.00682039997727063, -0.00274824040086975, 
    0.00445497119085701, -0.0200715167414251, -0.0172889092121903, 
    -0.0183097186084778, -0.00761068348240157, -0.019018744890486, 
    -0.00025262293205146, -0.0344974648260728, -0.0152223555564475, 
    -0.0020841576187069, -0.00183501446133657, -0.011794501394087, 
    -0.0229041856915202, 0.00796636153169424, -0.00229185373026946, 
    0.0251957167931911, -0.00629001005823519, 0.0181198183060087, 
    -0.0184232757504815, 0.049462958278229, 0.0148696918674201, 
    0.0149036102244975, 0.0071220259227979, -0.00164412962271088, 
    0.00315885138916578, -0.00466651772109416, 0.0296688259387658, 
    -0.00698475717864006, 0.00506839151556176, 0.0287125717104718, 
    0.0199037970427923, -0.00843964401884836, -0.00650954814458908, 
    0.00808833264229265, -0.00954095971123521, 0.000485354797368999, 
    0.0010823910051565, -0.0107780560665635, -0.00399074270905228, 
    0.0109014023267533, -0.00105720807106899, -0.00889838999687957
    ), Month = c(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
    6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
    11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4
    ), Year = c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
    2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
    2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 
    2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 
    2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2004, 2004, 
    2004, 2004)), row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame")
```

And here is data for the risk free return dput(dfRF[1:50,])

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(10987, 11016, 11047, 11077, 
11108, 11138, 11169, 11200, 11230, 11261, 11291, 11322, 11353, 
11381, 11412, 11442, 11473, 11503, 11534, 11565, 11595, 11626, 
11656, 11687, 11718, 11746, 11777, 11807, 11838, 11868, 11899, 
11930, 11960, 11991, 12021, 12052, 12083, 12111, 12142, 12172, 
12203, 12233, 12264, 12295, 12325, 12356, 12386, 12417, 12448, 
12477, 12508), class = "Date"), `Rf(1m)` = c("0.00482", "0.00486", 
"0.00492", "0.00528", "0.00525", "0.00548", "0.00558", "0.00586", 
"0.00604", "0.00613", "0.00619", "0.00627", "0.00613", "0.00608", 
"0.00613", "0.00632", "0.00601", "0.00614", "0.00599", "0.00593", 
"0.00598", "0.00587", "0.00588", "0.00548", "0.00555", "0.00554", 
"0.00558", "0.00560", "0.00558", "0.00586", "0.00600", "0.00594", 
"0.00595", "0.00594", "0.00602", "0.00551", "0.00508", "0.00474", 
"0.00473", "0.00435", "0.00423", "0.00348", "0.00306", "0.00259", 
"0.00234", "0.00237", "0.00242", "0.00207", "0.00183", "0.00163", 
"0.00162"), Month = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3
), Year = c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 
2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 
2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2004, 2004, 2004)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -51L), groups = structure(list(
    Date = structure(c(10987, 11016, 11047, 11077, 11108, 11138, 
    11169, 11200, 11230, 11261, 11291, 11322, 11353, 11381, 11412, 
    11442, 11473, 11503, 11534, 11565, 11595, 11626, 11656, 11687, 
    11718, 11746, 11777, 11807, 11838, 11868, 11899, 11930, 11960, 
    11991, 12021, 12052, 12083, 12111, 12142, 12172, 12203, 12233, 
    12264, 12295, 12325, 12356, 12386, 12417, 12448, 12477, 12508
    ), class = "Date"), Month = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
    10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 
    3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
    9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3), Year = c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
    2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 
    2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
    2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 
    2002, 2002, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 
    2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2004, 2004, 2004), .rows = list(1L, 
        2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
        15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
        26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 
        37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 
        48L, 49L, 50L, 51L)), row.names = c(NA, -51L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound like join `dfNAV` and `dfRF` using `Month` and `Year` as identifiers. Take all columns from `dfNAV` and `Rf` from `dfRF`.

**base R**:

```
merge(dfNAV, dfRF, all.x = T)
```

**Tidyverse**:

PS: You should install package: `install.packages("dplyr")`

```
library(dplyr) 
dfNAV %>% 
  left_join(dfRF)
```

Comment: Hey @nurandi. That almost did the trick! we have a few dates that does not end with the last day as the return is not registered every day (holidays/weekends etc). It skips end dates such as 28.4.2000 for one given fund. As the date for that month in dfRF is 30.4.2000. How can I make these match up? Other than that thank you for great input!

Comment: Can you please elaborate your problem in the question, with input sample and expected output?

Comment: Our data in dfNAV i grouped by Name of the mutual fund. The return (Net Asset Value, NAV) is given by the last value of each month the fund has been active. the risk risk free rate is in another data frame called dfRF, and they are ending at the last day of each month, regardless wether the exchange was closed this day or not. We therefor struggle to merge the two datasets correctly, as not all dates in dfNAV gets assigned the right value from dfRF. We have also tried using daily risk free rates to make sure the dates line up, as they do not in the monthly. I hope this made it clearer. Thanks!

Comment: I the other words, you want to take Rf of the last day of each month, and join it to NAV?